# IIOS IPAD No Unload,beforeunloador, paghide events

Tags: ios, ipad, model-view-controller

I have a MVC web database application where the records are basically documents with items.

Documents are locked, not items and they locked by code when the user looks in any of 4 or 5 different screens for any given document.
there is a 10 minute time out on the record locks.  The user does not do anything with the record for 10 minutes and another can take the record.  There is code that detects the lock was lost and taken by someone else.  It works fine and is technically sound.

The workflow of the application relies on the lock being released when the user leaves the screen or closes the browser, or if they press the refresh button.

These are work fine on windows and android but not on ipad.

I understand there is no

> beforeunload

on ios but I though there was

> unload

or

> pageHide

neither of these work.

Here is my code.

> var isOnIOS = navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i)||
>   navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i); var eventName = isOnIOS ?
>   "pageHide" : "beforeunload";
>
> window.addEventListener(eventName, function (event) {
>   ReleaseRecordLock();  } );

This code works on all mentioned platforms except that the events don't fire on IOS.

It looks to me that this is deliberate on Apple's part so I an not thinking it will change.

So now the question.

What can I do to ensure that these records get unlocked if a user changes screens or closes the browser.  If they don't no users will be able to access the document for 10 minutes which will not be acceptable.

Thanks

Edit...  I don't need pop ups or notification.  I just need reliable unlocking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above none of the events that are supposed to work actually fire. pageHide and unload do nothing.

I found mentions of how to get around this problem but no details so I though I would detail it here.

This solutions works with areas and standard sites.

My solution to get around part of this was to detect if the browser is running on IOS and if so to change the link in the menu.

```
     <li>
        @{
           if(Request.UserAgent.Contains("iPad") || Request.UserAgent.Contains("iPhone"))
           {
              <a onclick="IOSReleaseLock('controller', 'action')" href="javascript:void(0);">LinkText</a>
           }
           else
           {
               @Html.ActionLink("link Text","action","controller",new { Area = "Tasks" },null);
           }                           
        }                                                     
    </li>
```

Every single link in the application has to have a function called IOSReleaseLock() available or the solution will not work.   Not all pages lock records, only those that actually change documents.  Reports, and basic website functions such as change password,  log out,  and the sys admin stuff do not need record locks.

At this point I have 2 versions of IOSReleaseLock()

This is the version that is used on pages that do not required unlocking.

```
 function IOSReleaseLock(_controller, _action)
    {
        var url = '/__controller__/__action__/';
        url = url.replace('__controller__', _controller);
        url = url.replace('__action__', _action);
        window.location.href = url;
    }
```

This is the version that is placed on pages that required unlocking.

```
function IOSReleaseLock(_controller, _action )
{
    var url = '/__controller__/__action__/';
    url = url.replace('__controller__', _controller);
    url = url.replace('__action__', _action);
    UnloadingRecordLockRelease();      
    window.location.href = url;    
}
```

Every link has a wrapper so every single page must load a version of IOSReleaseLock().  This includes your /home/index or where ever your application starts.   If you miss one then once you are on that page your menu system links will not work anymore.

Pages that require the  UnloadingRecordLockRelease() function load that version and the pages that do not require unlocking load the first version.

On IOS every time you click a link, IOSReleaseLock() is called. This may seem to be obvious, but for clarity,  the version of IOSReleaseLock() that executes is the version that is on the current page, not the version on the page you are going to.

So as long as the user stays on the site and does not close the browser then the records are unlocked correctly.

When the user logs out all records are unlocked but I have no solution for when the browser tab is closed or when the browser is closed without the user logging out.